# Java sockets: parallel clients, one server: some of the client messages are missing

Tags: java, sockets

### Problem

I have 1000 threads that send messages to my server.

Client code looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Client(i));
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    private static class Client implements Runnable {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);

        private final int id;

        Client(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
                LOG.debug("Client {} connects to server...", id);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                LOG.debug("Client {} sends message...", id);
                writer.write("Client id: " + id);
                writer.flush();
                LOG.info("Client {} sent message (port {})", id, socket.getLocalPort());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And server code looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        blocking();
    }

    private static void blocking() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8080, 1, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"))) {
            LOG.debug("Server started...");
            while (true) {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                LOG.info("New client! (port {})", client.getPort());
                Thread.sleep(100);
                client.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I'm running this program I expect to see `# of clients server accepted` ≥ `# of clients who successfully sent message`. But sometimes it is not! Sometimes we have `# of clients server accepted` < `# of clients who successfully sent message`.

### What I've tried

1. tweak backlog parameter
2. synchronize write to server between clients

### Current thoughts

Based on timestamps in logs it seems that clients that are not handled actually send message when server sleeps. But I don't understand, where they send them... Maybe they stay in backlog queue, send message, disconnect and after that they are removed from the queue?

### Configuration

macOS, openjdk-17

Comment: have you tried testing it with fewer threads first, making sure it works the way you intended and gradually scaling up testing as you go? 10 -> 20 ->100 -> 250 -> 500 -> 1000 etc.

Comment: I've reproduced same problem with 100 threads. Couldn't reproduce with less (50), but maybe there just weren't enough attempts...
I also tried to tweak `sleep` time. When I set it to some high number (e.g. 20 seconds) problem is gone.

Comment: It does not seem relevant to me who actually closes connection - server or client. But I've done as you've suggested - removed `client.close()` from server side. Client already closed connection since I use try-catch-with-resources. 
Problem still persists, some clients send message, but server haven't even `accept`ed them...

Comment: What about creating a server with multiple connection threads? You wouldn't want a single server to have to handle all the connections one at a time? Why not divide the work between 4 server accept threads? See where that gets you.

Comment: Agree, I can rewrite server in some different manner - multiple threads, nio, etc...But I'm trying to understand what's the problem in the current configuration. For me it seems that I do not fully understand some part of my program: maybe how os works with sockets, maybe how java handles sockets internally...So my goal here is mainly an educational one (that's why code is so simple)

Comment: My guess would be that some of your clients timeout trying to connect to the server. What's the behavior of `socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));`? Does it wait forever, or does it wait for a certain amount of time? And what about creating a collection of Sockets for your server instead of using only 1 connections for all those threads. Then when the client closes the connection on its end, your server will go through clean up all the sockets once their closed? Similar to how you wait for all your threads to shut down on your client side.

Comment: They indeed timeout and this is expected. I can see `Operation timed out` exceptions in logs. So, `# clients that server accepted` <`# clients that sent message` < 1000. But if I see `Client {} sent message (port {})` in logs it means that this particular client did not timeout, and I only count this clients as "clients that sent message". So it seems to me that there's some other problem
I didn't quite understand the reasoning behind  "collection of Sockets on server side". How exactly closing of sockets will affect correlation between "sent requests" and "number of accepted clients"?